# jquery-datepicker issues formatting date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 datepickers in jquery where I add a single day to the date of one picker and assign it to another date picker like so:

```
 /*assign date pickers*/
        $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd-yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });

        $("#MainContent_txtExpectedShipDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                if (date) {
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(date);
                }

            }
        });
```

Notice the `onSelect` function adds a single date and assigns it to `#MainContent_txtActualShipDate` but the value it gets is "TUE APR 24 2012 00:00:00".
I want it to be simply '04/24/2012' so mm/dd/yyyy.  I read the jquery ui docs and looked up some examples on stackoverflow but none of them worked.  Is there anyone that can look at this code and edit to get the format I want?

## Edit

Here is what I change it to:

```
        $("#MainContent_txtExpectedShipDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd-yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                if (date) {
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd-yyyy', date);
                    $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(formattedDate); 

//                    $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(date);
                }

            }
        });
```

But it shows the year twice 04/12/20122012.

## Answer

Here is what worked for others in the future:

```
/*assign date pickers*/
        $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });

        $("#MainContent_txtExpectedShipDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                if (date) {
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                    $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(formattedDate); 
                }

            }
        });
        /*end assign date pickers*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Got it my format was wrong I needed 'mm/dd/yy'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`formatDate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function:

```
var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
$("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(formattedDate);
```

Comment: For some reason it shows the year twice...the result is 4/26/20122012 ??

Comment: yours is correctly formatting the date but the result shows like so: 4/26/20122012 ?  See my code in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the date like

`$('#MainContent_txtActualShipDate').datepicker("setDate", date);`

If this doesn't work,

`$("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear());`

Answer (score 0):

You missed dateFormat try this:

```
/*assign date pickers*/
    $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });

    $("#MainContent_txtExpectedShipDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

            if (date) {
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                $("#MainContent_txtActualShipDate").val(formattedDate); 
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesnt work it still assigns the long string to txtActualShipDate

Comment: you have add yyyy reduce it to yy

Answer (score 0):

You had the wrong dateFormat, it needs to be 'dd/mm/yy'

I also tend to just add a class to any field that requires datepicker. Therefore, you can just do something like this...

```
$(".DatePick").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', gotoCurrent: true });
```

Saves having to assign it more than once.